# Specific example needed. ERROR: Already defined .obj + One or more multiple defined symbols

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have recently been studying C++ and I am having a little trouble with using classes in separate files. I think I have the basic understanding down, but I keep receiving this same error and I'm not sure how to overcome it. I have searched online for a while, but answers seem vague and use a lot of technical jargon that someone new to c++, such as myself, would not understand. If you could I would appreciate some help on this issue with specific explanation as to why MY code is not working in this particular instance. Please, and thank you.

[Code and subsequent errors...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjJgc.png)

**NOTE!** I am asking for an explanation specific to my code of exactly what needs to be done. Not a general answer as to what may be the problem. Seeing the problem solved will greatly help me in understanding the issue. I am having a very difficult time understanding the vague, general, and seemingly guessy responses of similar questions. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Next time please put your code into the question. It is generally looked down upon to have links to other pages and pictures containing code

Answer (score 1):

You declare a variable `ARITH math;` in the header, and then include it in two different source files. So you get two copies of the variable.

Just declare it in main.cpp, where it is used, and remove it from the header.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. So I should establish my object in the file that I am calling the functions, not in the .h files where I access my class?

Comment: The header is for things that are common to several files. Things that you just need locally are better declared where needed.

Comment: Cool. Thank you again for the help.